# Prusa MINI 0.6 mm nozzle print fail

Tags: print-quality, prusaslicer, prusa-mini

Setup:

- Prusa MINI with 0.6 mm Nozzle.
- Firmware 4.0.5
- Bootloader version 1.0.0
- Buddy board 1.0.2
- Prusa Slicer 2.2.0
- Using the OctoPrint 1.4.0 on OctoPi 0.17.0 with serial
  connection.
- Find the G-code [here](https://gist.github.com/powtac/5ea2c492e65cbc48a9f6e5c4a7fc6f3e)
- The amf is found [here](https://gist.github.com/powtac/a3754240e18cd15b9df994e435e2cd74)

After I switched to the 0.6 mm Nozzle I have massive problems to get good results, as you can see in the picture below. The two parts in the front starting to have from the height of about 5 mm very bad lines. I realized it 5 mm later and I set manually the temperature from 215 to 220 °C which seemed to solved the problem a little bit, but still not perfect results.

As you can see in the second picture, I removed the 0.6 mm nozzle to make sure it fitted. I did, there is no filament on the thread.

Test: I did use some noname filament with the 0.6 mm nozzle first and had bad results as well. The problem mainly was, that the temperature (215 °C) was too low. So I raised it for the noname filament to 240 ° which seemed to solve the problem but quality was not perfect, so I switched to the Prusa Polymers filament to make sure the issue is not related to the filament.

So what could be the issue here?

[image][image][image]

Comment: There are strong indicators that the problem is related to the flow rate setting.

Comment: So, what speeds are you printing then?